# Add a small tab on left drawer

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I am new to android dev. I have a problem of adding a small tab on my left drawer.
Because it may be hard for user to detect that I have a left drawer so I want to add a tab to let people notice.
Here's the screenshot of my app.enter image description here
[image]
[image]
I hope it can have a small tab like this
[image]
Can you give me some hint to start?

Comment: Have you tried with sliding drawer ?

Comment: This library might be of help: https://github.com/NikolaDespotoski/DrawerLayoutEdgeToggle

I think everyone gets the idea of having drawer, I don't know why you are putting this at all. :)

Comment: You should probably make those images smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put a view on the left of your layout using relative layout and on click of that view you can just open the drawer by calling:

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.START)
```

This will open the drawer in the same way it open when action bar icon is clicked.